# update jsonb with update_column vs update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using `rails 7` with `postgresql`

I'm trying to update an `jsonb` attribute on my model

with

```js
model.update_columns("published_data = jsonb_set(published_data, '{structure}',  '[\"file\"]')")
```

it rises an error

> undefined method `transform_keys'

but with

```js
Model.where(id: model.id).update_all("published_data = jsonb_set(published_data, '{structure}',  '[\"file\"]')")
```

it works perfecly fine

I don't understand why

Answer (score 2):

`update_all` updates multiple records in a single query, while `update_columns` updates only one record. In other words:

```
User.where(active: true).update_all(deleted_at: nil)
```

will update all active users, in contrast to `update_columns`:

```
User.find(id: 42).update_columns(deleted_at: nil)
```

which only works for one record.

Therefore, the following will return `NoMethodError: undefined method 'update_columns' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`:

```
User.where(active: true).update_columns(deleted_at: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `update_columns` expects a hash as a parameter, whereas `update_all` allows either a string or a hash.